# Meteor JS api always return text/html content type unexpected "<" error

Tags: meteor

I have created api to get a list of all posts. It's working fine on the local server but when I put the code
on aws server it returns error Unexpected "<"
in postman and in the header it always shows http://prntscr.com/o1tbax. I have set content-type in response header also. Then I have removed query to get data from collection and to test API just pass static response. But still, it returns an error.

```
 Router.route('/api/postslist/:userid',{where: 'server'})

.get(function(){
var response;
response ={
            "errorCode" : false,
            "statusMessage" : "Arguments List",
            "data":"resp test"
          }

     //this.response.setHeader('ContentType','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
 this.response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  this.response.end(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are telling your server to interpret the incoming data as JSON, which is why you are getting that error.

You don't say which router you are using, but if you were doing it using express on the server, your initialisation code will look like this:

```
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: false }))
```

and any method will receive the data as JSON, eg

```
app.get('/my/api',apiCallBack) // res.body passed to apiCallBack is json
```